# JSON object changes properties

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a chrome extension, I have to iterate through a dictionary and transfer data from the objects that are in there to another objects, I store the last ones in an array, this problem happened. Here is the output: [json_object_err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvXwK.png) Here is the desired output:
Here is my code:

```
var active_observers = {};
var participants_data = [];

function save_partcipants_data() {
    var participant_data = {
        name: "",
        words: 0,
        id: "",
        positive_marks: 0
    }
    for (let el in active_observers) {
        var finded = false;
        participant_data.name = active_observers[el].user_name;
        participant_data.words = Math.round(active_observers[el].speak_counter / 2.15);
        participant_data.id = active_observers[el].user_id;
        participant_data.positive_marks = active_observers[el].positive_marks;
        for (let i in participants_data) {
            if (participants_data[i].name === participant_data.name) {
                participants_data[i].words += participant_data.words;
                participants_data[i].positive_marks += participant_data.positive_marks;
                finded = true;
                console.log("object:");
                console.log(participant_data);
                console.log("list:");
                console.log(participants_data);
            }
        }
        if (!finded) {
            participants_data.push(participant_data);
            console.log("object:");
            console.log(participant_data);
            console.log("list:");
            console.log(participants_data);
        }
    }
}



 active_observers[user_id] = {
                    "user_name": user_name,
                    "user_id": user_id,
                    "speak_counter": 0,
                    "user_observer": observer,
                    "positive_marks": 0
                };
var active_observers = {};
var participants_data = [];
save_partcipants_data();
```

Comment: please share your inputs & desired outputs

Comment: I mean it is the same object isn't it?